# Word processor that handles right-to-left-languages / Complex Text Layout well

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

I find that LibreOffice is really not user-friendly for writers using right-to-left languages. I'm used to MS Office.

Which word processor can I use in Ubuntu that handles right-to-left languages well?

- It should be capable of CTL (Complex Text Layout)
- Advanced tools should work properly with non-English fonts and formats (some of LibreOffice's don't)
- *Clone formatting* should work on RTL fonts? (LibreOffice Writer's doesn't)
- It should be able to change page number fonts to RTL fonts
- It should justify the text correctly (LibreOffice Writer can't)
- It should handle the direction of fonts in combined text of RTL & LTR?
- RTL format should work in whatever formula entering (equation) method is used? (in LibreOffice it doesn't)

Comment: Libre office is most likely to support what you want, perhaps ask on their forums. For alternates see https://www.tecmint.com/microsoft-office-alternatives-for-linux/

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/

Comment: I had used libreoffice writer alot. it really sucks. expect they edit the program and add some functionality

Comment: Try one of the alternates I suggested. See https://www.calligra.org/words/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.